# Center the second line of an equation

Tags: equations, amsmath, align

How do I get the following output?

```
f a b c =
    <centered definition of f>
g a b c d =
    <centered definition of g>
```

These are definition of functions, but the bodies are big; I would like to flush the function and arguments left, but center the body.

The difficulty is that the length of (function and parameters) + (function definition) is greater than the length of a column. I couldn't figure a way to do this with any of `multline`, `align`, `alignat`, and `flalign`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abuse `flalign` `;-)` Flushing the first part to the margin doesn't seem good, in my opinion, so I provided two macros for pushing it forward; with `\rhide` you get alignment to the right end, conversely with `\lhide`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\rhide}[2]{\mathrlap{\hspace{#1}\mathllap{#2}}}
\newcommand{\lhide}[2]{\mathrlap{\hspace{#1}#2}}

\begin{document}


\begin{flalign*}
\mathrlap{f a b c ={}}\\
&&    <very very very very  long centered definition of f>&&\\
\mathrlap{g a b c d ={}}\\
&&    <very very very very  long centered definition of g>&&
\end{flalign*}

\begin{flalign*}
\rhide{8em}{f a b c ={}}\\
&&    <very very very very  long centered definition of f>&&\\
\rhide{8em}{g a b c d ={}}\\
&&    <very very very very  long centered definition of g>&&
\end{flalign*}

\begin{flalign*}
\lhide{4em}{f a b c ={}}\\
&&    <very very very very  long centered definition of f>&&\\
\lhide{4em}{g a b c d ={}}\\
&&    <very very very very  long centered definition of g>&&
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If a tricky solution is also allowed... We use the fact, that `gather` centers the lines. Tricky is `\intertext`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{gather*}
\intertext{$f a b c ={}$}
    <very very very very  long centered definition of f>\\
\intertext{$g a b c d ={}$}\\
    <very very very very  long centered definition of g>
\end{gather*}


\begin{gather*}
\intertext{\hfill$f a b c ={}$}
    <very very very very  long centered definition of f>\\
\intertext{\hfill$g a b c d ={}$}\\
    <very very very very  long centered definition of g>
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, that is pretty neat; but I'll still wait for other suggestions, I was hoping to learn about something that would also generalize to aligning right :)

Comment: @Clément Oh, aligning right is very easy. Please see my extendend version (without changing the picture).

Comment: Nice! But what if you want to to align the *body* of the definition right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just making the font size of the body smaller? I imagine that would make it easier to use one of those environments effectively. Or try using a `tabular` environment?

Comment: Conference submission, can't choose the font size :/